# can files from localhost be used as web_accessible_resources?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I've been looking around google for an answer but could not find it for now... Can use a file in my localhost as a path for "web_accessible_resources"?

Comment: No, only files in the extension directory/package can be used.

Comment: @wOxxOm you are my saviour.